# NSBundle pathForResource returns nil with indeed exists boundle resource

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that many same questions be solved, but I also don't know how to apply those answer to my application :(

- I specify copy boundle resource, please pay attention to `JSPatch.js`

[image]

- I find that `JSPatch.js` indeed exists in Application *.app

[image]

- I always receive nil result

[image]

could anyone help me please ?..

Comment: Oh, this is a strange one... sorry, i'm out of ideas

Comment: @webo80 thanks for your time, I wonder that maybe `build for profiling` which specify schema `build configure` of `release` mode caused issue but not really sure  : (